Proving Non-Semi-Decidability of Language L - Seeking Reduction Strategy
I'm working on a problem involving the language
 =
{

∣
time
(

)
≤
∣

∣
+
1
for all words 

}.
The language consists of words
 where the Turing machine
 halts within
∣

∣
+
1
steps for every possible input

I want to prove that this language

is not semi-decidable by reducing from a known non-semi-decidable problem, like the complement of the Halting Problem ¬H
. However, I'm encountering issues with ensuring that the reduction property
⟨,⟩ ∈ ¬ ⟺

(
⟨

,

⟩
)
∈
.
The challenge arises because, in the Halting Problem, there are inputs where the machine halts within
∣

∣
+
1
steps and others where it doesn't halt at all. This makes it difficult to construct a reduction that preserves the necessary properties to show that
 is not semi-decidable.
Has anyone faced a similar issue or can suggest a reliable reduction strategy to prove the non-semi-decidability of
 ? Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

Can you [edit] your post to tell us where you encountered this problem, and credit the source of the exercise/task/problem?  What does the notation Mw refer to?

You can, for example, let $f(\langle M, x\rangle)$ be the code of a Turing machine $M'$ that, for an input $y$,

runs $M$ on $x$ for $|y|$ steps,
if $M$ halted, keeps running forever, otherwise stops.

If you set things up correctly (you may have to mess with constants), then $f(\langle M, x \rangle) \in L$ iff ($\forall y$, $M'(y)$ halts in $|y|+1$ steps) iff ($\forall y$, $M(x)$ does not halt in $|y|$ steps) iff $M(x)$ does not halt.
